# Blender is encoding only the first half of my video?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, encoding

I'm using Blender purely as a video editor.

I'm trying to render the final product, but every time I try rendering it, only the first 2:38 (or so) of the 6:44 minute video gets done.

When I hover my cursor over the unopened file, it lists the length at `00:06:44`, but only `2:38` is viewable. I've tried adjusting things like frame rate (I've switched it to `23.98 fps` like the source video instead of `24 fps`), and checked that the start and end of the render coincides with the frames of the total video (so it's set to render frames `1` to `9691`) but that didnt change anything. I've also tried rendering it as an `FFmpeg` (instead of an `AVI jpeg` like I've done successfully with other videos) and that let me briefly view the entire video but then became unwatchable every time I tried to open it subsequently.

What's going on? Is there a way I can fix this or maybe even expand the existing rendered file so I can see the entire video?

*I tried rendering just the second half of the video. I had it start around where the cutoff was. The finished product ended up being less than a second long. I'm guessing the bit that actually showed up was the last bit of what was showing before.*

Comment: You could try rendering as an image sequence, then, in the compositing editor, render as an .avi, but I have not tried this at all, and do not know if it would work.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like most likely there is some kind of error either in the rendering or the format. Does the video show up in the preview for that part? You can try rendering only the second half and see if the video is there, or if it is black, etc. Does the video continue playing to the end, just is black, or stop altogether? As mentioned, you can try an image sequence for that portion and see if it renders out. If so, you know it is at least working and showing up correctly for that portion, and must simply be a format error of some kind, not an actual issue with the rendering.

Comment: I updated the post. The finished product from the render stops playing at 2:38 like it's the end of the video. Not even a black screen. When I've tried using the render in Microsoft Video Editor, it shows the full length of the video, but at 2:38 it just shows the last image at 2:38 continuously.